# How can I get a list of installed centos packages by only reading from the filesystem?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

I am writing a tool for analyzing images and have full access to an image's filesystem.

I want to produce a list of all installed packages with name and version info. However, I do not want to actually run the VM as I do not trust it.

I am aware of commands like `rpm -qa` but am not sure of any way of getting the data from just reading files (which must be what the rpm command is doing).

Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could extract the rpmdb from your filesystem: all the files under `/var/lib/rpm/`.

Then you could still use `rpm` to query the packages, but without running the vm: If you put that **rpmdb** inside another fake filesystem.

I tried this out, seems like `rpm` searches by default its database under `/usr/lib/sysimage/rpm`, so I did the following:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/fakeroot/usr/lib/sysimage/rpm/
scp other-machine:/var/lib/rpm/* /tmp/fakeroot/usr/lib/sysimage/rpm/
rpm --root /tmp/fakeroot -qa
```

as you can see I copied the `rpm` database from another machine, and I can now query its packages.

Comment: I like that solution, however my application might not always run on a rhel based machine and might be missing yum :/

Comment: I never talked about `yum`. But you would need an `rpm`-based os to use this solution. Other option is to start parsing those **berkely-DB** files yourself... good luck with that :)

Comment: Ah yes sorry I meant rpm, Yeah I think that might have to be my approach haha. Thanks!!!